# How is it possible to initialize a struct, if it has non-copyable members?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to create a struct, which has some primitive members and a unique_ptr, which can not be copied. I tried to solve it by disabling copy and adding the default move constructor, but it does not work. The compiler tries to find a 2 argument constructor, but there isn't any:

```
 In function 'int main()':
37:3: error: no matching function for call to 'ListElem::ListElem(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
37:3: note: candidates are:
25:2: note: ListElem::ListElem(ListElem&&)
25:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
20:5: note: constexpr ListElem::ListElem()
20:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

The code is:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MyObj {
    public:
        virtual ~MyObj(){}
};

class MyObj2 : public MyObj{
    public:
        virtual ~MyObj2(){}
};

struct ListElem {
    std::unique_ptr<MyObj> item;
    int some_counter = 0;

    ListElem() = default;

    ListElem(ListElem const& e) = delete;
    ListElem& operator=(ListElem const& e) = delete;

    ListElem(ListElem&& e) = default;
    ListElem& operator=(ListElem&& e) = default;

};

int main()
{
  std::vector<ListElem> elems;

  ListElem item{
      std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj2()),
      10
  };
  elems.push_back(std::move(item));
}
```

How could I solve this error?

---

**Edit**

I changed the constructor to this:

```
ListElem(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>&& _item, int _some_counter): item(_item), some_counter(_some_counter) {}
```

But now I get `error: use of deleted function`

Comment: How about making a constructor taking the arguments you want to pass? Or having no declared or defined constructors at all (thereby making the structure an aggregate)?

Comment: I'm confused, you just need a constructor that accepts `std::unique_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr&&` and `int`?

Comment: Are you using c++11 exactly by any chance? Not c++14.

Comment: c++14. I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all constructor declarations from your class<sup>(1)</sup>. The class will then be an aggregate and will be initialisable with *aggregate initialisation* (what you're trying to do). Note that there's no need to manually delete the copy constructor or default the move constructor, both will happen automatically.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b12641c6b1513f8)

Of couse, the alternative is to provide a two-parameter constructor taking the arguments you want to pass in. Note that even in this case, you don't need to manually delete & default the copy/move operations.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keep in mind that `struct` and `class` both introduce class types. The only difference between them is the implicit access control for bases and members (`public` and `private`, respectively); they are otherwise identical.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, and what the OP is stumbling on IMO, `struct`'s are classes too. The keyword `struct` does not by itself an aggregate make.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hm, it didn't even occur to me this could be the issue. I will try to weave it in.

Comment: I tried your code at http://cpp.sh/ but I still get the error. ( I use struct, because I would like to make all the members public by default )

Comment: @IterAtor The link you've posted doesn't lead to the code.

Comment: @IterAtor If I paste the code from my Coliru example to cpp.sh, it fails to build, you're right. Hower, on Coliru, both gcc and clang compile it, even in C++14 mode. I'd be inclined to say the cpp.sh failure is a bug of the gcc version they use (4.9 is quite old).

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a struct directly without constructor is called aggregate initialization. This works only in some cases. For eg. the class should not have any constructor on its own (defaulted ones are fine). It looks like some restrictions were lifted in c++14, so as posted in the other answer, it works fine in c++14 or later. But not in c++11. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZTFUz3

```
  ListElem item{
      std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj2()),
      10
  };
```

For your edit, the reason for failure is you missed to move the `unique_ptr`. Add `std::move` and it should work fine in both versions.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/uFmZvC

```
ListElem(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>&& _item, int _some_counter)
: item(std::move(_item)), 
some_counter(_some_counter) 
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the initialization of the member **some_counter**: this does not allow the aggregate initialization of the struct, check here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization, it is explained that the class (struct) should not have no default member initializers (since C++11 until C++14).

Here the code changed:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MyObj {
    public:
        virtual ~MyObj(){}
};

class MyObj2 : public MyObj{
    public:
        virtual ~MyObj2(){}
};

struct ListElem {
    std::unique_ptr<MyObj> item;
    int some_counter;

    ListElem() = default;

    ListElem(ListElem const& e) = delete;
    ListElem& operator=(ListElem const& e) = delete;

    ListElem(ListElem&& e) = default;
    ListElem& operator=(ListElem&& e) = default;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<ListElem> elems;

  ListElem item { std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj2()), 10};

  elems.push_back(std::move(item));
}
```

Link to code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/InZQwGKFyWKmCJrL